# Unable to add or find what was added

Tags: python, elasticsearch

So, I opened two `Python` prompts in `Ubuntu`. In one prompt I do this:

```
>>> from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
>>> import json
>>> db = Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}])
>>> doc = {'attr_12_':'admin','type':'object_1_','id':'1'}
>>> rs = db.index(index="reestr", doc_type="object_1_", body=doc)
>>> json.dumps(rs)
'{"_type": "object_1_", "_id": "pBZhz5VQTrGIgqYAiKFmTA", "created": true, "_version": 1, "_index": "reestr"}'
```

I then go to another window and do this:

```
>>> from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
>>> db = Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}])
>>> res = db.search(index="reestr",doc_type="object_1_",q={'type':'object_1_'})
>>> for r in res['hits']['hits']:
...     print(r)
...
>>>
```

So, as you can see, it couldn't find anything. I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The problem is definitely in this part `q={'type':'object_1_'}`. But the documentation is so heartless towards developers and does not provide enough examples. I guess the lack of examples is one of the major things that distracts developers from one technology and force them learn other (probably worse) technologies, which however have solid documentation.

Comment: I think, the solution should be like `q={do this and that:jump over there, make three steps to the right:run ahead}`. Who in the world does know this magic mantra?